# stunnel : SSL alert (read): warning: close notify

Tags: stunnel

we have a stunnel proxy server running on the same box. Basically, our app connects to stunnel proxy server in un-encrypted fashion, and this stunnel proxy server then connects to a remote server ( that remote server belongs to a different company) over TLS.

the relevant configuration are :

```
client=yes
accept=9998
connect=x.y.z.w:nnnn
verify=level 1
```

Occasionally, ( once every 2-3 weeks), the connection is down after running a few hours, with following stunnel log :

```
2018.04.02 10:05:37 LOG7[197784:140586247849728]: SSL alert (read): warning: close notify
2018.04.02 10:05:37 LOG7[197784:140586247849728]: SSL closed on SSL_read
2018.04.02 10:05:37 LOG7[197784:140586247849728]: Socket write shutdown
2018.04.02 10:05:37 LOG7[197784:140586247849728]: Socket closed on read
2018.04.02 10:05:37 LOG7[197784:140586247849728]: SSL write shutdown
2018.04.02 10:05:37 LOG7[197784:140586247849728]: SSL alert (write): warning: close notify
2018.04.02 10:05:37 LOG6[197784:140586247849728]: SSL_shutdown successfully sent close_notify
2018.04.02 10:05:37 LOG5[197784:140586247849728]: Connection closed: 25757163 bytes sent to SSL, 937186 bytes sent to socket
2018.04.02 10:05:37 LOG7[197784:140586247849728]: FIX session XXXXXX-XXX finished (1 left)
```

I am not very clear is it caused by the remote server ( belonging to a different company ) terminating the connection first ?

Any advice ?

Thanks in advance,
Frank